# Replace value dynamically with regular expression

Tags: .net, regex

I have a url like

```
http://www.somesite.com/$(someKey).php
```

I have a dictionary includes these keys, what I need is using the Regex to replace the `$(*)` with the value in the dictionary labeled with that key.

How can I do that?

Comment: Use the [`Regex.Replace()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.regex.replace.aspx) method.

Comment: @AlexFilipovici I know I should use it, but I don't know the patterns needed, and how to get the key from the input string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

a thing like this perhaps:

```
url = Regex.Replace(url , @"\$\(([^)]+)\)", delegate(Match m){ return dict[m.Groups[1]]; });
```

Answer (score 3):

You may use the [Regex.Replace Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.regex.replace.aspx). Try this:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var dict = new Dictionary<string, string>();
        dict.Add("someKey1", "MyPage1");
        dict.Add("someKey2", "MyPage2");

        var input = "http://www.somesite.com/$(someKey2).php";
        var output = Regex.Replace(input, @"\$\((.*?)\)", m => 
        {
            return dict[m.Groups[1].Value];
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: the pattern should be `\$\(.*?\)` - otherwise the match for `.*` is greedy and there are going to be problems for cases with 2 or more possible matches.

Comment: Thanks, that worked fine, but the key should not include the $() characters, Thanks any way :)

Comment: You are welcome. It was a little bit unclear in the OP how the keys in the dictionary would look like... I updated my answer with the proper replacement code.